# Compile ruby script for faster use

Tags: ruby, performance, compiler-construction

I have a ruby script of around 2200 lines which is being used repeatedly, so is there a way to convert it into binary or compile it so it runs faster.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that only [JRuby has a compiler](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyCompiler) which is good news if Java is your target platform and no help if not.

Perhaps you could re-architect your solution to include the Ruby interpreter in a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29) so that your script can be launched once and run continually as it receives input?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MRI, your best bet is to [optimize](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/inline_optimization.html) your code as the JIT compilation already delivers proven performance. You can also switch to 1.9 version as it is faster in various cases.